# Внучатый племянник — а как наоборот?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Допустим, у меня есть внучатые племянники — дети моей племянницы. А кто тогда я им? Как называется такой родственник? Не бабушка и не тетя, а как?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вы - двоюродная бабушка. Ну или дедушка.

Вообще русская система именования родства очень проста и универсальна.
Степень родства плюс разница в поколениях.

родной, двоюродный, троюродный... семиюродный... + (отец/сын) брат, дед/внук, прадед/правнук, прапрадед,

Имеется четыре исключения. 
Три общих и одно частное.

Общие: 
Двоюродный отец = дядя, Троюродный отец = двоюродный дядя и т.д.
Двоюродный сын = племянник, Троюродный сын = двоюродный племянник и т.д.
Двоюродный Я = брат, Троюродный Я = двоюродный брат и т.д.

Частное. Вместо "двоюродного внука" чаще используют "внучатый племянник". Но для "двоюродного деда" подобной традиции нет.

Я когда-то все описывал в деталях, могу поискать, если непонятно.

Вот русская система свойствА (некровного родства) совершенно уникальна, но это уже потребует отдельного разговора. Хотя могу тоже ссылки поискать...

А, вот попалось что-то приемлемое.
[Родственные связи | Домашний советник](http://www.advicehome.ru/page10.php)

Правда, не полное.

Вот на грамоте еще немного про совсем уж экзотических родственников
http://forum.gramota.ru/forum/read.php?f=1&i=41414&t=41383

Особенно - последние посты про "вуя", "стрыя" и производных от них.

Answer (score 0):

А я думаю, что сыну моего племянника я двоюродная тётя.